# An extra blank page is created when merging two PCL with ghostscript

Tags: c, linux, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am converting two PCL documents to a single PDF document. 
There are only two pages but the PDF documents ended up with 3. One extra empty page.

```
snprintf( cmd, sizeof( cmd ) - 1,
        "/home/rds/app/src/gpcl919/ghostpcl-9.19-linux-x86/gpcl6-919 "
        "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%s "
        "-dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dSusbsetFonts=true "
        "-dEmbededFonts=true -dCompatibilityLevel=\"1.3\" "
        "-dPDFSETTING=\"/printer\" %s  %s", szPdfPath, szPclPath1, szPclPath2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really possible to tell what your problem is without seeing the content of the two files. PCL is a simplistic language, and its possible that there is some aspect of page ejection that is causing a genuine extra page (because the interpreter believes the page is marked) when the input is closed.

A few observations; you should use the current version of GhostPCL (9.21). I would recommend never using PDFSETTINGS, especially when the input is from a different language, stick with the defaults. There is no 'EmbededFonts' switch, there's 'EmbedAllFonts', 'AlwaysEmbed' and 'NeverEmbed'. The latter two take an array of font names which should not be embedded.